# How to make suitable border and shadow for a widget created by CustomClipper

Tags: dart, flutter, clip-path

I have a `Container` widget inside of a `ClipPath` which uses a `CustomClipper`. Everything works fine, I have the desired widget shape.

However, I could not find a way to make a shadow for this custom shaped Widget.
Also, I want to have an outline(border) that follows the edges of this custom widget automatically.

Again no luck. I tried `BoxDecoration:border`, `BoxDecoration:boxShadow`, `ShapeDecoration:shape`, `ShapeDecoration:shadows`, `Material:Elevation`, etc..

Answer (score 10):

based on @Bohdan Uhrynovskiy I investigated further and came up with this solution:

```
CustomPaint(
  painter: BoxShadowPainter(),
  child: ClipPath(
  clipper: MyClipper(), //my CustomClipper
  child: Container(), // my widgets inside
)));


class BoxShadowPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    // here are my custom shapes
    path.moveTo(size.width, size.height * 0.14);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height * 1.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width - (size.width  *0.99) , size.height);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawShadow(path, Colors.black45, 3.0, false);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

You must need to provide your own custom paths in `paint()` method of `BoxShadowPainter`

Comment: What does `false` signify in the last argument?

Comment: `transparentOccluder` from docs here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawShadow.html

Comment: Could you please explain what a transparent Occluder does? The docs provide no information.

Comment: The transparentOccluder argument should be true if the occluding object is not opaque.

Answer (score 1):

Look at source code of the [library](https://github.com/leonardocaldas/flutter-polygon-clipper). Feature implemented in this library seems very similar to your task.

You have to implement CustomPainter that draws shadows and borders.

```
return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1.0,
        child: CustomPaint(
            painter: BoxShadowPainter(specs, boxShadows),
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: Polygon(specs),
              child: child,
            )));
```