# Can I draw a custom box shadow in Flutter using Canvas in a CustomPaint?

Tags: flutter

It's clear how to draw a shadow with an elevation property but what if I want to have the shadow centered for example?

Comment: if tou want to draw a shadow using `Canvas` just check `Canvas` class documentation

Comment: The drawShadow method doesn't allow for the customization of the shadow beyond the elevation property (I want a custom shadow).

Comment: so what is custom in it? a color? a specific blur? if so, instead of `drawShadow` use other `Canvas` primitive calls

Comment: Yes, I realized I can simply copy the source code used for BoxShadow and apply it to my paths.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found a solution:

I can simply go into the source code for the BoxShadow widget and apply the path properties they used to my own paths.

[Here's the source code.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/387f885481cd8441237680de0cfcd0802c0af48c/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/box_shadow.dart)

Here's the code that I used to create a shadow for a custom path (rather than a circle or rectangle with a border radius) that allowed me to create a custom shadow rather than using the elevation preset.

```
    canvas.drawPath(
       Path()
          ..addRect(
              Rect.fromPoints(Offset(-15, -15), Offset(size.width+15, size.height+15)))
          ..addOval(
              Rect.fromPoints(Offset(0, 0), Offset(size.width, size.height)))
          ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd,
        Paint() 
        ..color= Colors.black.withAlpha(shadowAlpha)
        ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.normal, convertRadiusToSigma(3))
    );

    static double convertRadiusToSigma(double radius) {
        return radius * 0.57735 + 0.5;
    }
```

Comment: could you post your solution code to get the idea what exactly you were trying to acheive? thanks

Comment: Yep! There you go.

Comment: @JonAird Thanks for sharing this. So does the `MaskFilter` do the trick here; following your custom path and apply a custom shadow? If yes, I will look into it more. I am trying to accomplish what you did only for an inside shadow. Do you think there is a parameter which allows having the shadow gradient grow towards the center of the Path instead of outside of it?

Answer (score 1):

To draw shadow on `CustomPaint` you can use [painter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint/painter.html).

```
CustomPaint(
  painter: BoxShadowPainter(),
  child: ClipPath(
  clipper: MyClipper(), //my CustomClipper
  child: Container(), // my widgets inside
)));
```

check my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753355/how-to-make-suitable-border-and-shadow-for-a-widget-created-by-customclipper/55014394#55014394)

Comment: Your answer seems to use the drawShadow method which still uses the elevation property and doesn't allow for the customization of the shadow (such as offset, blur etc.)